# Kendo UI Mobile loading button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a function that loads a button with javascript, but I don't know how to trigger it to look like a button.

My code looks like the following:

```
$("#loadDiv").html("<a data-click='Event' type='button' data-role='button'>My Button</a>");
```

It will then only show the link "My Button". How do I then trigger it to change it into a button?

In Jquery mobile I did the following:

```
$("#loadDiv").trigger('create');
```

Anyone know how to do this is kendo ui mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look through the [Data Attribute Initialisation article](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/data-attribute-initialization) from the Kendo docs.